# Does Python have a "PYTHONBUFFERED" Environment Variable?

Tags: python

I see many people setting `ENV PYTHONBUFFERED=1` in their Dockerfile. Just [Google it](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22PYTHONBUFFERED%22).

I know that [PYTHONUNBUFFERED](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONUNBUFFERED) exists (emphasis on the "UN").

So my basic question is, does `PYTHONBUFFERED` exist, do a lot of people just misspell it, or is it a concept specific to Docker?

Example seen in a Dockerfile:

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 python:3.10-buster
ENV PYTHONBUFFERED=1
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While in many cases it's impossible to prove a negative, this isn't one of them.

[Searching the CPython source code for `PYTHONBUFFERED` has no matches](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Apython%2Fcpython%20PYTHONBUFFERED&type=code). This is, thus, human error.